# Automatically clear "Find what" parameter after using Find and Replace box

Tags: microsoft-excel, find, find-and-replace, replacement

Is there any way to clear "Find what" (Ctrl+F) search parameter when after a search using "Find and Replace" on Excel? I realized it is not possigble to use Ctrl+A to select all the text inside the "Find what" box, so every time I need to clear this parameter I need to manually delete each character.

1. The best solution would be to automatically reset the Find and Replace to default after every search.
2. Second best solution would be to enable Ctrl+A inside Find and Replace box.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to automatically clear all entered parameters after the search. I don't think it's a viable need. This seems to require you to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use <kbd>Home</kbd> or <kbd>End</kbd> to navigate at the beginning or end of the "Find what" box. Then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> to select the whole content of the box.